# What exactl hex information is telling me to send? Where LC and xx yy zz is not clear to me

Tags: embedded, usb, protocols

This is not clear to understand, what exactly i have to send as command? does it mean i have to send in two step? (its a usb hardware connected to pc where i can send the command to get informations)

1) first one has to be 
`00 A4 08 0c 04 df 01 40 31 {LC?? what does it mean}` ?

2) second one has to be
`00 b0 xx yy zz` {what is exactly xx and yy and zz has to be??}

***Reference saying as below:***

```
To select those files, you have to use:

00 A4 08 0c 04 df 01 40 xx Lc
00                         : ISO CLAss (~standard ISO)
   A4                      : ISO file_select INStruction
      08 0c                : P1 P2 for this operation (otherwise you get an error...)
            04             : length of the 'path'
               df 01       : directory for Id data
                     40 xx : the files id
                        31 : owner's identity (names, birth,...)
                        33 : owner's address
                        35 : owner's picture
                           Lc is the expected answer length (?)

Once the file is successfully selected (SW1:SW2 == 90:00), 
one can 'binary_read' the content with

00 b0 xx yy zz
00                         : ISO CLAss (~standard ISO APDU)
   b0                      : ISO read_binary INStruction
      xx yy                : offset in the file (256*xx)+yy
            zz             : number of bytes to read
```

Comment: Where is the reference coming from? Why all these tags? Could you link to the reference?

Comment: I'm just going to state this right now, in advance. You're working with government ID stuff. In no jurisdiction, locale, or other unit, shall the authors of any answers or comments, on this post, Stack Overflow, Stack exchange, its agents, or other related entities be responsible for any damages, whether incidental or consequential that may arise from asking here or using answers. You take all risks with this identification system.

Comment: I understand that, and all others understand it too, and its not new i have been working ages with such government devices which i pay from my pocket and it follows there protocol (we buy such device ourself). Shell we go with the description details what xx, yy, zz and lc here meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions are clearly answered by the comments in the specification.

`Lc` is the expected length of the response.

In the 'binary_read', `xx` and `yy` are respectively the MSB and LSB of a 16 bit value for file offset, and `zz` is the length in bytes of the block to read.

If you want to accces the offset *n* then:

```
xx = n / 256 ;
yy = n % 256 ;
```

or alternatively:

```
xx = (n >> 8) & 0xff ;
yy = n & 0xff ;
```